# Taking configuration backups from Azure webapp wwwroot folder

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to take specific configuration backup in Azure webapp wwwroot folder with below powershell script which was working fine in public App service plan(Standard and Premium) but the same powershell script is not working fine in Private App service plan(Isolated(App service Environment) - I1,I2,I3). Please find the code below.

Code:

```
Import-Module Kudu-api
  $userNm="`$Testapp"
  $password="*******"
  $token = New-KuduAuthorizationToken $userNm $password
  $sitename="Testapp"
  Set-Location "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Backups"
  sleep -Seconds 2
  Receive-KuduFile $sitename $token '/site/wwwroot/appsettings.json' ./appsettings.json`
```

Getting the below error when trying the above script in Isolated(I1) appservice plan:
Error : Invoke-RestMethod : The remote name could not be resolved: 'Testapp.scm.azurewebsites.net'

Please suggest how we can resolve this.

Comment: Based on the error looks like the issue is with the kudu url. for a isolated app service environment the kudu url will be in the below format 
App in Isolated tier (App Service Environment):
https://<app-name>.scm.<ase-name>.p.azurewebsites.net 
And the url you are requesting is for standard & premium app service
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/resources-kudu#access-kudu-for-your-app

Comment: The script which I have shared is working fine in standard and premium tiers but the same script we tested for Isolated (App Service Environment) in Powershell ISE application but getting the mentioned error. The error I shared is for isolated (App Service Environment). In the script we didn't included kudu URL. Do we need to add ASE Kudu URL in script ? Please suggest.

Comment: could you please help me whether are you using this kudu-api module form the below git hub https://github.com/mobzystems/Kudu-API ?

Comment: Yes, we already imported kudu-api module. After importing kudu-api module the script which I shared above is working fine for web apps hosted on standard and premium tiers but the same script is not working for App Service Environment applications.